# Pass array as parameter to proc in TASM?

Tags: arrays, tasm

I'm trying to create a proc in TASM that accepts arrays as parameters. Problem is, the result is all messed up. This is the code:

```
TextParameter       equ [bp+8]
MenuColorParameter  equ [bp+6]
RowToPrint          equ [bp+4]
PrintBar    proc
            push bp
            mov bp, sp
            mov dh, RowToPrint
            mov dl, 0
            mov bh, 0
            mov ah, 2
            int 10h
            mov si, 0
            mov cx, 1
    @@Print:
            mov ah, 9
            mov al, [TextParameter+si]
            mov bl, [MenuColorParameter+si]
            int 10h
            mov ah, 2
            inc dl
            int 10h
            inc si
            cmp si, MENU_LEN ; const in DATASEG
            jc @@Print
            mov ah, 2
            mov bh, 0
            mov dl, 0
            mov dh, 2
            int 10h
            pop bp
            ret 6
PrintBar    endp
```

When referencing the array through the DATASEG (as in mov al, Array[si]), the proc works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Michael's answer, I found the problem - int 10h ah=9 and int 10h ah=2 expect bh as the video page number. After assigning al and bl, I needed to `mov bh, 0`. The @@Print label is now this:

```
@@Print:
        mov ah, 9
        mov bx, TextParameter
        mov al, [bx+si]
        mov bx, MenuColorParameter
        mov bl, [bx+si]
        mov bh, 0
        int 10h
        mov ah, 2
        inc dl
        int 10h
        inc si
        cmp si, MENU_LEN ; const in DATASEG
        jc @@Print
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're passing the arrays by-address (i.e. their offsets), since the arguments seem to be 2 bytes each. If so, you need to first load that address into a register, and then add `si` and do another read from memory:

```
mov bx, TextParameter      ; expands to mov bx,[bp+8]
mov al, [bx+si]
mov bx, MenuColorParameter ; expands to mov bx,[bp+6]
mov bl, [bx+si]
```

Comment: Now it's printing nothing, which I guess IS progress?

Comment: From seeing just this procedure it's difficult to say why that might be. Stepping through the code in a debugger should help you find any remaining issues faster.